# Filling DataGridView with file names from a folder

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to fill my DataGridView with file names from certain folder.
This is what I have done so far:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\m2104\Desktop\test");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("File Name");

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]); 
                table.Rows.Add(file.Name);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;


        }
```

But nothing is happening. 
Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: This isn't neither C nor C++. Why did you set these tags?

Comment: Why is this in the CellContentClicked ??

Comment: @ThomasSablik - They're gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling this function from button click event.

```
private void loadFileNames()
{
     String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\m2104\Desktop\test");
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.Columns.Add("File Name");

     for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
     {
          FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
          DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
          dr[0] = file.Name;
          table.Rows.Add(dr);
     }

     dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

  }
```